# Webserver blocking other servers but not clients

Tags: server

I am currently pentesting a webserver and found out that its subdomain is blocked when pinged from another server (I tried pinging it w/ my Digital Ocean server and other ping tools from websites). But i can access its subdomain with my devices. also i tried using a VPN to check if it is only blocked by country IP but i can also access the subdomains even with VPN (with my devices).

Is there a way i can access the subdomains of that website with my server? Can i install a VPN client to my server? if so how can i then access it with ssh?

[EDIT]

I used a proxy site to visit the subdmain and it worked. I will try to install a proxy client to my server and see if it can ccess the subdomain

Comment: it might just be looking at the headers. heck, it might just be looking at user-agent.

Comment: I still don't know how it worked but i somehow bypassed there blocking by assigning my floating ip on digitalocean as my gateway.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just blocking ping?